# How do I use the onclick event to link to a web page instead of href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

I have an anchor tag that has an href. I need to add a string after the last / in the href from an input text box. I have tried to add the value of the input box to the href with no success. Can I add the value to the link string using the onclick event? How can this get accomplish using jquery? Here is the code:

```
//This is the Search Button
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').attr("href","/fighters/search/");

//This is the Input box
var sft = $('$switch-fighter-text').val();
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your HTML and the click event handler?  That would help.  Also are you trying to change the href on click of the link and have your browser go to the changed link, or changing it on click of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it'll take the href of the original link and add the value of the element with id "switch-fighter-text"

```
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').click(function(){
  window.location=$(this).attr("href")+$('#switch-fighter-text').val();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do here but if you could provide more code that would be useful.  Here's an example of what I think you might be trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var $link = $('#link1');
    //add to the href
    $link.attr('href', $link.attr('href') + "?id=1");
});

//note that if you want to prevent the link from submitting do like so
$('#link1').click(function(){

    //force redirect to a specific url, adding to the href on the fly
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + "&user=me";

    return false; //prevents href from changing window.location

});

</script>
<body>
    <input id="submit1" type="Submit" value="Submit"></input>
    <a id="link1" href="somelink/test.html">Link</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').click(function(){
   window.location="/fighters/search/"+$('$switch-fighter-text').val();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I think you want a `return false` there

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('$switch-fighter-text').change(function() {
    var link = $('#switch-fighter-search-button-link');
    link.attr('href', link.attr('href') + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: And what happens if you change it more than once?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').attr("href", $('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').attr("href") + $('$switch-fighter-text').val() );
```

This will add your textbox's value to the already existing href src

but i think that can change the href src after you clicked on the page will not work.
So use

```
onclick=" window.location='"' + $('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').attr("href") + $('$switch-fighter-text').val(); + '"'; "
```